# Opening new application windows in foreground, as usual?

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, window, gnome-tweaks

Ubuntu 20.04. Until recently I had following behaviour:

- press Ctrl+Alt+T -> new window with Gnome Terminal appears, gets focus, I can directly start typing commands...

Since recently this behaviour changed into:

- press Ctrl+Alt+T -> new window with Gnome Terminal opens in the background, a notification is displayed, when I click the notification or switch in an other way to the window, I can start using the terminal

This change concerns also other applications, e.g. in Google Chrome, I press Ctrl+N and new window opens in the background, with a notification, instead of going to the foreground directly...

I did not intentionally change it in any settings. Is that a consequence of some upgrade? Anyway I would like to return the behaviour back as it was before. Any idea?

I didn't find any settings that would seem relevant neither in Ubuntu Settings, nor in Gnome Tweaks.

Comment: After almost 50'000 downloads of that extension one would think the #Gnome developers would show mercy with us and solve this by a settings switch :-/

Answer (score 1):

For 22.04 I managed to fix this:

1. with the extension linked above https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/234/steal-my-focus/
2. following the workaround listed as a comment (which basically edits the metadata to support the current version).
3. To restart gnome I had to log out the current user (instead of the mentioned Alt+F2 > r)

Here are the modified steps:

1. Temporary disable or remove the GNOME shell integration from your browser
2. Reload the page and download .zip by clicking Download > 3.20 > 4
3. unzip ~/Downloads/steal-my-focus@kagesenshi.org.v4.shell-extension.zip -d ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/steal-my-focus@kagesenshi.org && sed -i 's/"3.20"/"3.20","40","41","42"/' ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/steal-my-focus@kagesenshi.org/metadata.json
4. Logout the current user and log back in (previously: alt+f2 > r)
5. gnome-extensions enable steal-my-focus@kagesenshi.org

Comment: I was being pestered by the window opening in the background for quite sometime. On stumbling upon this answer, I was happy that there's a solution to the issue. I ended up using the ["NoAnnoyance" extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1236/noannoyance/), though. The steps needed to install that were simpler. I followed the ["Manual installation" procedure](https://github.com/sindex/no-annoyance#manual-installation).

Answer (score 0):

There are Gnome shell extension that can solve this super-annoying behaviour. See https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/12/quick-tip-remove-window-is-ready-notification-focus-window-immediately/

Comment: Extension is not available for my system: `Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS`.

Answer (score -1):

user1182474's answer did not work for me, but going into dconf-editor and changing /org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/focus-new-windows from 'strict' to 'smart' did. I liked not having to install an extension.

Comment: This did not work for me, too, because it is already on smart.